# Select all columns on a group by throws error

Tags: sql, group-by, syntax-error, northwind

I ran a query against Northwind database `Products Table` like below

`select * from Northwind.dbo.Products GROUP BY CategoryID` and i was hit with a error. I am sure you will also be hit by same error. So what is the correct statement that i need to execute to group all products with respect to their category id's.

**edit:** this like really helped understand a lot

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `GROUP BY` in a query, all items in your `SELECT` statement must either be contained as part of an aggregate function, e.g. `Sum()` or `Count()`, else they will also need to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Because you are using `SELECT *`, this is equivalent to listing ALL columns in your `SELECT`.

Therefore, either list them all in the `GROUP BY` too, use aggregating functions for the rest where possible, or only select the `CategoryID`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an Aggregate function and then group by any non-aggregated columns.

I recommend reading up on [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).

Comment: Absolutely not.  You haven't told us what you want to select, so me giving you the "exact sql" is not an option.  You need to understand the technology if you hope to use it, not ask people to do it for you.  I have told you why you are getting the error and how to fix it.  Go forth and learn!!!